# Prove convergence of this sequence $f(n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}= \left(\frac{10+in}{n^2 + 2in}\right)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

I am having this sequence $f(n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}= (\frac{10+in}{n^2 + 2in})^n$

Is this sequence bounded/ convergent?

---

Thoughts:

$lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{10+in}{n^2 + 2in})=lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{\frac{10}{n^2}+\frac{i}{n}}{1 + \frac{2i}{n}})=\frac{0+0}{1+0}=0$

=> $lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{10+in}{n^2 + 2in})^n=0$

---

Questions:

1. Is this correct?
2. **Is this sentence correct: $lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=0$ => $lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n)^n=0$?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n=0$ implies there exists $n_0\in \mathbb N$ such that $\vert a_n\vert<\frac{1}{2}$ for all $n\geq n_0$. Thus $\vert a_n^n\vert<\frac{1}{2^n}$ for all $n\geq n_0$. Thus $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n^n=0$.